# Increasing render time from importing wrls

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have a script that imports wrl's for different increments/instants of time for a deforming object.
The script scales, rotates, cleans and boolean functions the wrl-imported object before it render (Cycles). 
Then the script deletes the wrl-imported object
(`bpy.data.objects.remove(bpy.data.objects[ob.name])`)
and imports a new wrl. And so on and so on.

The first render takes about 2 minutes, the second a little bit longer and the 50th takes 15 minutes. There are no significant differences between the 1st and the 50th render.

Anyone have a tip on what this could be caused by or how to troubleshoot it?

Comment: what version of blender and can we see the script that deletes the objects?

Comment: Version: 2.79a

The part of the script that deletes the objects is: bpy.data.objects.remove(bpy.data.objects[ob.name])

Comment: There must be something getting left behind. Run it for a few frames and check the Outliner for extra objects/links. If that does not make it apparent. Try running it for a 100 frames export the resulting .blend and then from a new file Append from the saved .blend. You will see all the data/objects etc